# 4-Pole High Pass filter Algorithm in CPP: ¿mathematical base?

Tags: c++, audio, filter, juce

Hello I found this algorithm as 4-Pole High Pass filter, tested it and it works, but I have not found any information related to his mathematical base, or algorithm it is based on. I need to understand the pieces of code I use, so if you can help, I'll be grateful

```
twopi = 8.0f * atan(1.0f);
float c = (float)exp((-1.0) * twopi * frequency / getSampleRate());
for (int channel = 0; channel < totalNumInputChannels; ++channel)
    {
        auto* outData = buffer.getWritePointer(channel);
        auto* inData = buffer.getReadPointer(channel);
        for (sample = 0; sample < buffer.getNumSamples(); sample++)
        {
            input = *(inData + sample) - pole4[channel] * quality;

            if (input > 1.0f) input = 1.0f;
            if (input < -1.0f) input = -1.0f;
            input = 1.5f * input - 0.5f * (input * input * input);

            pole1[channel] = input * (1.0f - c) + pole1[channel] * c ;
            pole2[channel] = pole1[channel] * (1.0f - c) + pole2[channel] * c;
            pole3[channel] = pole2[channel] * (1.0f - c) + pole3[channel] * c;
            pole4[channel] = pole3[channel] * (1.0f - c) + pole4[channel] * c;
            
            //The subtraction causes the filter to do a highpass
            outputs[channel] = input - pole4[channel];

            
            *(outData + sample) = outputs[channel];
            
            
            

        }
        // ..do something to the data...
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `c`?

Comment: added in algorithm. sorry. It looks like a mathematical constant

Comment: added twopi definition :) @Damien

Comment: Google IIR Filter, A discrete, high pass filter is a form of that.